# Vue replacing "el" component instead of rendering inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web

I don't know if this is a standard feature but Vue is replacing the element specified by "el" when the instance is created, instead of rendering inside of it.

if I use an id to reference the "el" then it works fine. ie,

```
new Vue({el: "div#app", render: h => h("span", {}, "Hello World")})
```

which will render as:

```
<body><div id="app"><span>Hello World</span></div></body>
```

but if I use a JS Element object as "el" then it replaces that element altogether.

```
const divElement = document.querySelector("div#app");
new Vue({el: divElement, render: h => h("span", {}, "Hello World")});
```

will render as:

```
<body><span>Hello World</span></body>
```

is it supposed to do that, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is some confusion on your side. I just prepared a sample where:

```
const el = document.getElementById("app");
new Vue({ el: el, render: (h) => h(App) });
```

Successfully renders to:

```
<body><div id="app">// content here</div></body>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-swartz-yie0l?file=/src/main.js

But you still need to keep in mind that  is not an element of DOM you had before vue mounted there but a virtual representation of it.

From vue documentation:

> The provided element merely serves as a mounting point. Unlike in Vue 1.x, the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases. It is therefore not recommended to mount the root instance to  or .

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el

Comment: thanks for the response. could you check this one out https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-meadow-d7cro?file=/index.html